# How to send a woocommerce cart items in CF7 form email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, cart, contact-form-7

I need to send Woocommerce cart items in the email by Contact Form 7 plugin.
I want to make a quick order form on my checkout page only with phone field
but send the cart details in email as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

Put this code into your **functions.php** file

```
/* Get a cart details as a text */
 function get_cart_content_as_text() {
   $cart_contents = WC()->cart->get_cart();
   $cart_text = '';
   $cart_total = 0;
   foreach ($cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
       $product = $cart_item['data'];
       $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
       $sum = $cart_item['line_total'];
       $cart_total += $sum;
       $product_name = $product->get_name();
       $cart_text .= "Product: $product_name x $quantity Subtotal: $sum \n";
   }
   $cart_text .= "---\n";
   $cart_text .= "Total: $cart_total";
   return $cart_text;
}

 /* create a new tag for CF7 */

 function cf7_add_cart_content_tag() {
   wpcf7_add_form_tag('cart_content', 'cf7_cart_content_handler');
}

function cf7_cart_content_handler($tag) {
   $cart_content_text = get_cart_content_as_text();
   return '<textarea name="cart_content" readonly>' . esc_textarea($cart_content_text) . 
 '</textarea>';
}

add_action('wpcf7_init', 'cf7_add_cart_content_tag');
```

Then use new tag **[cart_content]** in your form