# Get user latest WooCommerce order ID to use it with Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7, orders

On my website, when someone orders a specific product, he is redirected (using the “Thanks You URL” field in the product data) to a page where the customer have to fill out a form (made with Contact Form 7 obviously).

What I would want is to get the latest order ID from the customer (knowing that he has to be logged in to order) and put it in the email sent to me and the customer when the form is filled.

Any idea on how someone could do that ?

Thanks !

I'm quite bad at this and couldn't find anything related to this specific question unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last order from a logged in customer, you can use the following code:

```php
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders([
    'limit'    => 1,
    'type'     => 'shop_order', 
    'status'   => wc_get_is_paid_statuses(), 
    'customer' => get_current_user_id(), 
    'order'    => 'DESC',
]);

if ( ! empty($customer_orders) ) {
    $order = reset($customer_orders); // Last order object
    
    // Display the order ID (for example)
    echo '<p>Order ID: ' . $order->get_id() . '</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>There is no orders yet</p>';
}
```

There are already some threads in Stack OverFlow showing how to add a variable value to a Contact Form 7 field…

Related:

- [Pass some WooCommerce product data to Contact Form 7 enquiry form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413068/pass-some-woocommerce-product-data-to-contact-form-7-enquiry-form/66414597#66414597)
- [How to send a woocommerce cart items in CF7 form email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222251/how-to-send-a-woocommerce-cart-items-in-cf7-form-email)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)